# How to delete a TcpChannel object in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I'm having some troubles with `TcpChannel`. I want to create a channel, give remote access to an object, let's say, a server and after doing all this, close the channel. The problem is that I might need to re-open the same channel later, in the same port, and I'm having some hard time trying to do this.

for connection purposes I only do:

```
var channel = new TcpChannel(port);

Console.WriteLine("Start Connection received at Server");
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

//Initiate remote service as Marshal
RemotingServices.Marshal(this, "Server", typeof(Server));
```

then to close it, i just do:

```
Console.WriteLine("Stop Connection at Server");

channel.StopListening(null);
RemotingServices.Disconnect(this);
ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(channel);
channel = null;
```

After this if I try to create a new tcpChannel instance, i get an exception saying that the tcpChannel connections are unique, they must be on different ports.

So, how can i close the tcpChannel? :S

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having trouble reopening it between different sessions of the same application or in the same session? If it's the latter you could just open the channel when the app starts and then close/unregister it when the app shuts down.

Comment: @Paul Sasik I am having troubles because the tcpChannel is only closed after all connections are closed as well, so I need to end all acesses to my remote object.I tought i could do that by doing Remoting.Disconnect(object), but it doesn't seems to work with already shared remoted objects, i must do that by hand. I'll try to do that now. Thanks for all your help, I was amased by all your support and how fast you helped us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your close code are working.
recheck the logs, you miss the "Stop Connection at Server" somewhere.

**Update:**

there the my log **(no errors)**:
Start Connection received at Server
Stop Connection at Server
Start Connection received at Server
Stop Connection at Server

there the implementation code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        channel = new TcpChannel(port);

        Trace.WriteLine("Start Connection received at Server");
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);


        //Initiate remote service as Marshal
        RemotingServices.Marshal(this, "Server", typeof(Server));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Stop Connection at Server");

        channel.StopListening(null);
        RemotingServices.Disconnect(this);
        ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(channel);
        channel = null;
    }
```

Comment: The code is working, and the TcpChannel is being "closed". However when I try to do channel = new TcpChannel(oldPort); it throws a exception saying that ports in tcpChannel are exclusive. Somehow, the tcpChannel ain't being closed...

Comment: @matutano : no errors, i closed and reopened without error (and when i am trying to open twice, i am receiving your error)

Comment: @matutano i mean its working when no remote servers connected, so the problem is to disconnect remote servers first.

Comment: I was just thinking about that, that code really works and thats because there isn't any remote servers connected to it. I've tryied to do the same by running the set of servers with only one connected (so there wasn't any entity remotly connected), and it worked perfectly, wasn't suposed RemotingServices.Disconnect to end all remote services?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to stop and start listening on the same port you need to explicitly call [start listening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.tcp.tcpserverchannel.startlistening.aspx). You can loose the last three lines of the code after StopListening and preserve and reuse the object until your application goes down.

```
channel = new TcpChannel(port);
channel.StartListening(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I really must close the tcp connection. I have a set of servers that are controled by another entity. Is this entity that orders this set of servers to open and close some connections. My problem appears when that "master" entity, orders a server to open a tcpChannel, that had been previously opened. I really must close connections.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the channel property: exclusiveAddressUse to false.